# Getting value from UI Element

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm writing some stuff based on `UIAutomation` library in `C#` using White and I was wondering how I could get the actual value of an element? I mean text from `textbox`, `label` from `button` and numeric value from `numeric up-down`? AFAIK there's no method like `'GetValue'` in either. How to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using WPF this resource may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34038/UI-Automation-Framework-using-WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Text

```
Button.Text 
Label.Text
Textbox.Text
```

Etc Etc

Answer (score 0):

```
//for textbox
string your_needed_text1 = textBox1.text;
//for button
    string your_needed_text2 = Button1.text;
```